# Comparing first column of m x n matrix with each following using OR bitwise operation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix m x n filled randomly with ones and zeros except the last row which is filled sequentially from 1 to n (number of columns). I wish to compare first column with each of the following columns using OR bitwise operation. If the result of comparing two columns is vector filled with all ones I want to return vector of last elements of these two matrices. It does not 
matter if there are more than one columns comparable with the first, the program returns when the
first match is found. In opposite, I want to return the last element of the first column. How can I achieve this?

Example 1:

```
      1     0     0     1     0     0     1              
      1     0     1     1     0     0     1             
C =   1     1     1     1     0     0     1             
      0     1     1     1     0     1     1              
      2     3     5     6     7     9     11
```

In first example bitwise OR of first and second columns gives vector with all ones so we can return 
vector [2,3]

Example 2:

```
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0              
      1     0     1     1     0     0     1             
C =   1     1     1     1     0     0     1             
      0     0     1     1     0     1     1              
      2     3     5     6     7     9     11
```

In the second example first column does not have its pair that can return vector with all ones using OR operation, so we should return just the last element of first column which is [2]

Comment: How is `C` related to this example?

Comment: And what return do you want when they are not all ones in that matrix?

Comment: Is `Result` the result you are expecting or is it an assignement you are using elsewhere, i.e. not relevant to this problem?

Comment: I'm extracting matrices A and B from the C...I want to compare using OR (look at OR logical table) first column with all others and if the result is matrix with all ones I want to return vector filled just with last elements of succesfull compared matrices

Comment: @user3119422 If no matrix with all ones is found, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = C(end,[1 1+find(all(bsxfun(@or, C(1:end-1,1),C(1:end-1,2:end) )), 1)]);
```

Explanation:

`bsxfun(@or, ...)` computes the "or" operation between the first column and each of the other columns. For each column, if the result is all `true`'s, `all` will return a `true` value. Then `1+find(..., 1)` finds the column index of the first such `true`. From that, the final result is generated by indexing into `C`.

Comment: Wow Luis Mendo just one line and it works ! I tested it just on one matrix because I still did not find solution how to generate matrix random filled with 0 and 1 execpt last row which should be sequentially filled from 1 to n ...any idea?

Comment: @user3119422 Example with 4 rows and 7 columns: `C = [randi(2,4,7)-1; 1:7]`. See [`randi` doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randi.html). Or equivalently, use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rand.html): `C = [rand(4,7)<.5; 1:7]`

Comment: @LuisMendo I had the exact same idea and tools in mind. I guess tools like `bsxfun`, `all/any`, `min/max`, `find` are such useful tools for matrix related problems that one doesn't need to go beyond those, unless we are talking about built-in ones. You had my +1 already there for similarity in ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about 1 point but this code should work. If you want to stop after you found one solution pls uncomment the `break` command in the first if-case.

```
C= round(rand(5,10)*1); %Data
mySizes = size(C);      %Size of Data
D= 1:mySizes(2);        %values for last row
C = [C; D];             %adding last row to data
A = C(:,1);             %first column
result_found =0;        %control variable if a solution was found
for k=1:mySizes(2)-1    %loop
    B= C(:,k+1);        %k-th column
    if A(1:end-1,1) | B(1:end-1,1)  %comparing the k-th column with the first
        result= [A(end,1),B(end,1)]  %result
        result_found = 1;            %result has been found
         %break
    end    
end
if result_found ~=1
   result = A(end,1)                 %if no result has been found return last val of column 1
end
```

**Example:**

```
C= 0    0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
   1    1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1
   1    0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0
   0    1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
   0    0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0
   1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

result =

     1     3
```

Comment: The Minion, why your result is 1 3 when the first column can be ORed to give the result with all ones, so the result vector should be just last element of the first column 1 because matching is not found

Comment: @user3119422 But my first column (which you want to compare to right?) is (1 0 0 0 1 x) and my third column is (1 0 0 0 1 y) Thus the result you wanted is x,y.  You said that you don't want to compare the last rows of the columns but if the other elements match you want those elements as result. ANd obviously the first column will ALLWAYS be equal to the first column. If you want to check that the whole program doesn't make sence and you should rather just write `C(end,1)` to return the last row first column value.

Comment: The Minion, I'm comparing elements using OR operation,except last elements. So the result of (1 0 0 0 1 x) | (1 0 0 0 1 y) gives (1 0 0 0 1) which is not matrix with all ones as I need . Compare for example 6th and 10th colum (1 0 1 0 1) | (0 1 0 1 0) = (1 1 1 1 1) and because you got all ones return the last elements [6,10]

Comment: @user3119422 ok than i misunderstood your question. I edited my solution so that it works. Only the argument of the if-case had to be adjusted. (example changed (because of new compilation and rand-function).

Comment: The Minion, I checked the solution it works ! Thank you...Also I repaired my question so I hope so that it won't be negative anymore.